# How to add two connection strings in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, connection-string

How can I write for 2 database connection string to `app.config` in Visual Studio?

Fox example

```
Data Source=devsql;Initial Catalog=Pool;Max Pool Size=1000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

I want to add another connection string with a different value for `Initial Catalog` - how to do this please?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530284/multiple-sql-server-connection-strings-in-app-config-file)?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a second entry to your `<connectionStrings>` section in your `app.config` - use a different **name** to be able to keep the two apart:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FirstConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=devsql;Initial Catalog=Pool;Max Pool Size=1000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
         providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" />  
    <add name="SecondConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=devsql;Initial Catalog=SomeOtherDatabaseName;Max Pool Size=1000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
         providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Replace `System.Data.ProviderName` with the **actual** database provider name you're using ...

Comment: What about in visual studio in the Shared Data Source Properties on the General is there a wat to make it shorter like this Data Source=devsql;Initial Catalog=Pool;Max Pool Size=1000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True? Could I added another Initial Catalog within this string?

Comment: @DThomas221: not exactly sure what you're talking about - but **NO**; you **cannot** add two `Initial Catalog` values into a single connection string; if you want to connect to two separate databases - you need **two separate** (and complete) connection strings.

Comment: I figure out a another way to add this by creating a new Add New Data Source in Visual Studio plus I able to keep the same database connection string without make it longer.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a another way to add this by creating a new Add New Data Source in Visual Studio plus I able to keep the same database connection string without make it longer